# How does C preprocessor actually work?

Tags: c, macros

I made the code snippet simpler to explain

```
// Example 1

#define sum2(a, b) (a + b)
#define sum3(a, b, c) (sum2(a, sum2(b, c)))

sum3(1, 2, 3)    // will be expanded to ((1 + (2 + 3)))


// Example 2

#define score student_exam_score
#define print_score(student_exam_score) printf("%d\n", score)
#undef  score

print_score(80); // will be expanded to printf("%d\n", score);
                 // but not printf("%d\n", 80); that I expect
```

The first one is intuitive, and that kinds of codes exists in several places such as finding the maximum or minimum number. However, I want to use that technique to make my code clean and easy to read, so I replace the some words in a macro with a shorter and more meaningful name.

AFAIK, C preprocessor runs only once per compilation unit and only performs string replacement, but why `print_score` cannot be expanded to `printf("%d\n", 80);`?

This is the replacement procedure I guess:

```
#define score student_exam_score
#define print_score(student_exam_score) printf("%d\n", score)
#undef  score

print_score(80);

//  --> 

#define score student_exam_score  // runs this first
#define print_score(student_exam_score) printf("%d\n", student_exam_score)  // changed
#undef  score

print_score(80);

//  --> 

#define score student_exam_score
#define print_score(student_exam_score) printf("%d\n", student_exam_score)  // then this
#undef  score

printf("%d\n", 80);  // changed
```

Comment: print_score(80); => printf("%d\n", score) => printf("%d\n", student_exam_score), so that's the issue.

Comment: @BlackMamba Won't `print_score(student_exam_score) printf("%d\n", score)` be replaced with `print_score(student_exam_score) printf("%d\n", student_exam_score)` first?

Comment: "*C preprocessor runs only once per compilation unit*" and "*why `print_score` cannot be expanded to  `printf("%d\n", 80);`?*" The latter is exactly because of the former.

Comment: @Keivin Dong I  think  it is releated to the order of expland MARCO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a sequencing issue.  First the macros are defined, and `score` is undefined before it is ever used.  Then, when `print_score` is expanded, it first substitutes all instances of `student_exam_score`, of which there are none.  It then rescans the result, looking for further macros to expand, but there are none since `score` has been undefined and is no longer available.

Even if you moved `#undef score` down below the reference to `print_score`, it still wouldn't work since parameter substitution only happens once (`score` would be expanded but `student_exam_score` would not).

Note that `score` is not substituted into the body of `print_score` at the time is it defined.  Substitution only happens when the macro is instantiated, which is why `#undef score` results in the `score` macro having no effect whatsoever.

These examples will make it clearer.  First, consider the following:

```
#define foo bar
#define baz(bar) (foo)
baz(123)
```

This is expanded as follows:

```
    baz(123)
->  (foo)
->  (bar)
```

Expansion stops here.  Parameter substitution was done before `foo` was expanded, and does not happen again.

Now consider the following:

```
#define foo bar
#define baz(bar) (foo)
#undef foo
baz(123)
```

This is expanded as follows:

```
    baz(123)
->  (foo)
```

Expansion stops here because `foo` is no longer defined.  Its earlier definition had no effect on the definition of `baz`, because macro substitution does not happen when macros are defined.  It only happens when they are expanded.

Comment: Why is `score` undefined? I am not sure whether preprocessing has issue about undefined.

Comment: It's a sequencing issue.  `#undef score` undefines `score` before it has ever been used.  See the last paragraph in my answer, which I just added.

Comment: `#undef` exists just for not impacting the following code.

Comment: I understand what you want.  But it doesn't work the way you think it does.  `score` will not be expanded in the body of `print_score` until after `print_score` has been instantiated, but by then `score` is no longer defined.  If you look at the preprocessor output, you will understand.  But it doesn't really matter, since even if `score` were defined, it would still stop short of substituting the paremeter.

Comment: I start using `cpp` for checking the only-preprocessed output. I am still confused about why the first one works, but not mine. Isn't the first one also faced the problem?

Comment: I added some examples to explain what your case is doing.  Regarding your `sum2` and `sum3` example, this works because `sum3` is first exanded, then the result is rescanned and the `sum2` references are expanded.  Note that there is no issue with parameter substitution.  If you undefined `sum2` prior to referencing `sum3`, then the result would contain unexpanded references to `sum2`.

Comment: The last line is really helpful, and it really points out the problem.